# Cognos 11 using SDK can we Get Native SQl (generated sql)

Tags: sdk, cognos

I am able to get the report specification XML using SDK and in which I can get the SQL to database. However if we use module/package the report specification does not contains the native SQL. Similar to Get Generated SQL in report studio. Is there a way to get the Native SQL (Generated SQL) using SDK.
Thank you,
TSB

Answer (score 0):

I suppose yes, in cognos with SDK using BIBUS object looking for reportversion method and then SQL property.

There was sample code available on IBM for this, but it seems IBM has removed the URL.

http://www.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21344260

Comment: Thanks Amit for the pointer. Yes the link is broken. Will look into the documentation and update

Comment: Hi Amit, I was not able to get access to reportVersion object. I found in the documentation that reportVersion is present inside baseReport (authoredReport/reportView) but I was not able to get hold of it. Can you please point me on how to access reportVersion object?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can get the SQL via the [`reportService.validate()`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEP7J_11.1.0/com.ibm.swg.ba.cognos.ca_dg_sdk.doc/r_d15e203927.html#itf_validate_validateValidate) method.  Two issues that need to be dealt with, however, are 1) prompt values need to be provided, if any are needed, and 2) you will have to use the Cognos SDK [asynchronous conversation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEP7J_11.1.0/com.ibm.swg.ba.cognos.ca_dg_sdk.doc/i_d15e250479.html#bi_bus_api_running_reports_the_report_execution_conversation) in order to run the validation to completion and retrieve the result.

Learning and getting the asynchronous conversation to work can take some time, but there is sample code for validation in the samples provided in the Cognos root directory.  In Cognos 11, these samples are conveniently in the `samples` folder under the Cognos root.  You will find Java examples there demonstrating how to submit a request that uses the asynchronous conversation and do things like submit prompt values and tell Cognos you are waiting and still interested in the result.

If you can actually get the request to completion, the `detail` property of the response will include an `asynchDetailReportValidation` object that has a [`queryInfo` property](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEP7J_11.1.0/com.ibm.swg.ba.cognos.ca_dg_sdk.doc/r_d15e614152.html#bibus_asynchDetailReportValidation).  This XML will contain the SQL for each query the report would execute when run.